# C++ static_cast in gdb returns different result than gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, double

I am investigating an issue with strange behavior of gcc and gdb when static_casting long double to double. I have something like the following code:

```
const double xDelta = 60.0;
int xSplits = 3;
const long double xStepL = static_cast<long double>(xSplits) / xDelta;
const double xStep = static_cast<double>(xStepL);
```

Basically it divides 3/60, so the result should be 0.05. When operating with simple `double` values, the value of `xStep` was `0.050000000000000003`, so decided to use higher precision with 12 byte `long double`. The value of `xStepL` in the above example then was `0.05000000000000000000067762635780344`. When casting this value back to `double`, it is in fact `0.050000000000000003` again. However, when examining the value with gdb it prints the following:

```
(gdb) p xStep
$1 = 0.050000000000000003
(gdb) p static_cast<double>(xStepL)
$2 = 0.049999999999999996
```

Any idea why the results differ? I actually want it to be the second one. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

BTW, I am using GCC 4.3.4 and GDB 7.2.50.

Comment: `0.05` is not representable in binary floating point, so the actual value is going to be one of `0.050000000000000003` (`0x1.999999999999ap-5`) or `0.049999999999999996` (`0x1.9999999999999p-5`). The larger value is closer to `0.05` (`0x1.9...ap-5`), so you should prefer to end up with that value.

Comment: The value is later multiplied and casted to integer as an offset for memory access. Unfortunately, in this special case (which is a test case and the absolute boundary) it makes a difference and would exceed the available memory.

Comment: Possible solutions to the memory issue include testing for bounds and clamp (but this introduces a branch into the code), or to add a duplicate at the end of the memory block - but this only works if the access is read only.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the `static_casts` are not getting called with the same values. The value in the code is getting called with a higher precision register value, while the one called from gdb will be using a long double in memory. I'm not sure the exact places the compiler is allowed to do that, but I'm guessing this is one - so the answers can end up differing by one elp.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "higher precision register value"? I also experimented with GCCs __float128 type and ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Typically calculations with double are performed in higher precision registers and then switched back down to lower precision when stored back into memory. IIRC it used to often be 80bit intermediate values, but that may well be different now on 64b processors.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in gdb.

The instruction to cast from `long double` to `double` is a `fldt` (ten-byte floating-point load) followed by `fstpl` (8-byte floating point store).  When you perform a reduced-precision floating-point store it will round the operand, going from `0.05000000000000000000067762635780344` to `0.050000000000000003`.  It looks like gdb is instead truncating the operand, going from `0.05000000000000000000067762635780344` to `0.049999999999999996`.  In floating-point hexadecimal:

```
0x1.99999999999999999999ap-5 -> 0x1.999999999999ap-5 (gcc, correct)
0x1.99999999999999999999ap-5 -> 0x1.9999999999999p-5 (gdb, incorrect)
```

[Discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4772390#4772390) indicates this is fixed in recent versions of gdb (7.4.50).

Comment: I tested it with 7.4.1 from Debian Wheezy a minute ago and had the same (wrong) results. I will prove as soon as I get an even more recent version. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Tested it with the latest weekstone of gdb (7.4.50). If it's a bug, it's NOT FIXED. Same wrong results here.